# workflow with consolidation stage sometimes comes back as error or cancelled

Tags: workflow, infopath, permissions

I have created a form library which takes an InfoPath form as its default. there are several workflows that created after a form has been created. One of the workflows contains a consolidation stage where I change the permissions of the form so only the person who created it and another person has permissions to it. This works fine most of the time but when some people do it. it appears in the list as either error occurred or cancelled.
Any idea what could be doing this?